# fully encrypted MediaWiki base

Tags: encryption, mediawiki

Is it possible to completely encrypt a MediaWiki installation?

I'm not looking for a way to finely control access rights or have some encrypted articles or even just parts of articles encrypted.

What I want is that the whole information contained in the wiki isn't stored in plain text but encrypted.

Answer (score 4):

Do you care at which layer in the stack the encryption happens?

Short of massively modifying the source code to decrypt all DB queries (and that's ignoring the key management aspect), the best bet might be to encrypt the partition that the database lives on.

What is the reasoning behind it? There may be a better way.

Comment: If you aren't going to encrypt the entire system, and just a single partition, then you'll probably want to do something with swap as well.

Comment: First: The reason behind this is simply to be able to use a private wiki on a possibly shared server that might get compromised, or where the trust for the provider isn't as high as one would require for the data.

Comment: Encryption at a lower level might also work, yet I guess even with SSL connections, it wouldn't prevent eavesdropping on the server side. But perhaps it's a feasible compromise when the web host allows the creation of partitions (I presume that's only possible for (virtual) root-servers)